# Change of employer (within 2 years) for non-EU citizen having Blue Card

Tags: resident-permit, blue-card, employment, europe

I am an Indian IT professional who currently lives in Poland. I came to Poland on March 17 (with a work permit), and got my Blue Card on August 17; it is valid until  August 2020.

I got an offer from an Amsterdam IT company, but they are not interested in helping me out with documents.

Do I need to have a work permit The Netherlands?  As I would be terminating the job in Poland, do I need to hand in my existing Blue Card?

Is it better to wait for 2 years before thinking of changing jobs, in or outside of Poland?